# Viewing Flash Socket

Tags: flash, sockets

I have a flash (ActionScript 3.0) which uses socket connection to send data to the server.
Is there any way to view the sent socket data? (like http-requests in firebug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) if your data is HTTP(S).  Or "[pcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap)" is an option for the raw packet data.